# How to remove a prebuilt entity label from an utterance

Tags: machine-learning, azure-language-understanding

I'm training my LUIS app with utterances, and I've added the prebuilt entity "number".  I've noticed when you're labeling utterances for training, you can remove custom labels that are automatically guessed but you can't remove prebuilt entity labels.  For example, if I have this utterance:

[image]

I can click on `Person` (a custom entity I created) and remove that label but I can't do the same for `number` (the prebuilt entity).  I'd like to do it for this utterance because the number should actually be "point five" -- e.g. "0.5", and thus I want to label it with another entity that indicates it's a number.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately we cannot remove the prebuilt entity labels as the users have minimal control over it. If you are not satisfied with the quality of the existing prebuilt entity, then an alternative could be to either build your own simple entity or regular expression entity to replace it.